# How to read/write objects to xml?

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I am trying to make a XML Parser of sort that reads in chunks of a class object into a file and should also be able to edit the same.

The class structure is as follows

```
[Serializable]
public class Service
{
    public enum ServiceStatus { ACTIVE, INACTIVE, SUSPENDED };

    //Unique identifier for a service
    string _Id;
    public string Id 
    {   get{ return _Id;} 
        set{ _Id = value;} 
    }

    //Name of the service, for reference of the client
    string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    //URI where the service is hosted
    string _uri;
    public string Uri
    {
        get { return _uri; }
        set { _uri = value; }
    }

    //The state of the service
    ServiceStatus _status;
    public ServiceStatus Status
    {
        get { return _status;}
        set { _status = value; }
    }

    //the categories contained in the service instance

    public ICollection<Category> Categories;

    //collection of users/clients who can access this service
    public ICollection<Client> Clients;


    public Service()
    {
        _Id = null;
        _name = null;
        _uri = null;
        _status = ServiceStatus.ACTIVE;
        Categories = new List<Category>();
        Clients = new List<Client>();
    }
}
```

The Category class is as follows

```
public class Category
{
    //Unique identifier for a category
    string _Id;
    public string Id
    {
        get { return _Id; }
        set { _Id = value; }
    }

    //Name of the category, for reference of the client
    string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    //URI where the category is hosted
    string _uri;
    public string Uri
    {
        get { return _uri; }
        set { _uri = value; }
    }

    //Collection of pulses in this category

    public ICollection<Pulse> Pulses;

    public Category()
    {
        _Id = null;
        _name = null;
        _uri = null;
        Pulses = new List<Pulse>();
    }
}
```

The pulse class is a similar class with just id and name.

What would be the best way to read/write such objects in an xml file. The operation is read heavy and I would like to have the values read as accessible as possible, possible as array indexed or as a dictionary, but any form is fine.

Kindly suggest the simplest way. I am overwhelmed by the number of classes for XML in c#

Comment: Use class and property decorators combined with the `XmlSerializer` class. To get started I recommend reading through an article such as this one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2baksw0z(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

What about converting it into DataSet and the performing your operations?
XmlTextReader.ReadXml(reader);

Comment: I tried a few things .. but got messed.. It would be very nice of you if you could explain it a bit in detail.

Answer (score 0):

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(fileNamePath);

This will convert all your XML into DataSet. After converting XML into DataSet you can perform whatever operation you would like to do.